# Magnolia CMS - How can i change the value when i render in a content app of the class SelectFieldDefinition?

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

I have a content app of events, when I make a new event I have a field who belongs of class SelectFieldDefinition.
Inside my field definition, there is the node "options" of the multi selection and i have the property "value" where i input a value of my option field

[field definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfPCe.png)

The problem arrives when i show the option selected in my content app, because it is showing the option "value" instead of the property "label", and it´s very ugly (in apps/events/subApps/browser/workbench/contentViews/tree/columns)

[option value showing the property "label"][2]

[option selected showing the property "value"][3]

I read the documentation and I found a property called "valueProperty", but it doesn´t function

Also i,ve read this https: //documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Transforming+field+values

I can´t find this problem

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfPCe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own formatter class, see https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Column+definition - transformer classes are mean to transform the Vaadin items in dialogs into JCR form (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Now I can go into my formatter class but i don´t know how to change the value for label

```
    if (NodeUtil.isNodeType(node, EventsNodetypes.Events.NAME)) {
            // if the node has been mark as deleted, most of its properties - e.g. lastName, firstName - has been removed
            if(node.hasProperty("jcrCountry") ){
                node.getName();
                return PropertyUtil.getString(node, "jcrCountry", " ");


            }else{
                return node.getName();
            }
        }
```

Only i can render the same property of the jcrName property which is my first property in the dialog when I create an event

Here is the full class:

```
public class EventsNameColumnFormatter extends AbstractColumnFormatter<AbstractColumnDefinition> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractColumnDefinition.class);


    public EventsNameColumnFormatter(AbstractColumnDefinition definition) {
        super(definition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
        final Item jcrItem = getJcrItem(source, itemId);
        if (jcrItem != null && jcrItem.isNode()) {
            Node node = (Node) jcrItem;

            try {
                if (NodeUtil.isNodeType(node, NodeTypes.Folder.NAME)) {
                    return node.getName();
                }
            } catch (RepositoryException e) {
                log.warn("Unable to get name of folder for column", e);
            }

            try {
                if (NodeUtil.isNodeType(node, EventsNodetypes.Events.NAME)) {
                    // if the node has been mark as deleted, most of its properties - e.g. lastName, firstName - has been removed
                    if(node.hasProperty("jcrCountry") ){
                        node.getName();
                        return PropertyUtil.getString(node, "jcrCountry", " ");


                    }else{
                        return node.getName();
                    }
                }
            } catch (RepositoryException e) {
                log.warn("Unable to get name of contact for column", e);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```